# SQL Query to insert and update

Tags: sql

can I use insert query and update query together in a single SQL query. If it is possible then how can I write this query? in which format it has to write.

Comment: Are you talking of upsert(If records exists then update else insert) operation?

Comment: I want to update one column and insert into another column in a single time. May be upsert is the short form of update and insert. Can you give me a query format of UPSERT?

Comment: Are the columns of the same table?

Comment: Sounds like you try to update two columns at one time? Can you please provide an example for better understanding? Also tag the question with the dbms you use.

Comment: which sql db are you using?
Oracle, MySQL ?

Comment: Probably not. What's wrong with writing two seperate update and insert statements? Please post sample data and what actual dialect of SQL (SQL Server? Oracle?)

Answer (score 0):

I will post a snippet of query copying from source table to destination table to give you context and hint as to how it works, you can take it from there:

```
update  dst
set     col1 = src.col1
from    DestinationTable dst
join    SourceTable src
on      src.Key = dst.Key

insert  DestinationTable 
        (Key, col1)
select  Key
,       col1
from    SourceTable src
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    DestinationTable dst
        where   src.Key = dst.Key
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

If that is MySQL you can use `REPLACE` to either insert a new row or overwrite an existing one:

```
REPLACE INTO test VALUES (1, 'Old', '2014-08-20 18:47:00');
```

Comment: I want to update one column and insert into another column in a single time.